# Add/remove class on click, Jquery

Tags: jquery, button, click, addclass, removeclass

What is the best way to add and remove classes, clicking a button back and forth?

```
    $('button.hamburger').on('click', function(){
      $(this).addClass('is-active');
    });

    $('button.is-active').on('click', function(){
      $('button.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
    });
```

It doesn't remove .is-active class.

Do I need if statments to check whether the the element .hasClass()?

Answer (score 5):

You can use toggleClass() - Cheers.

```js
$("button.hamburger").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hamburger">Click me...</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the active class is adding dynamically, you need to use delegate,

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.is-active', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('is-active');
});
```

Or you can simply use toggleClass(),

```
$('button.hamburger').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});
```